# Page refresh from keyboard shortcut fires keypress event listener

Tags: javascript, events

I'm currently making a game to learn using javascript to manipulate the DOM and I'm having trouble. Currently I have an event listener so any key press will start my game which work event listener works. My problem is that if I refresh the page from the keyboard shortcut, cmd + r for mac, it is no longer listening for a key press. Even more strange is the fact that if a refresh the page from browser circular arrow refresh then my event listener works and is waiting for input. I suspect this is happening because the keyboard refresh causes the event listener to fire before everything is loaded and then the event listener is removed. I have tried all manner of ways to delay the firing but nothing seems to work. Here is my code

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
  const canvasEl = document.getElementById("game-canvas");
  const ctx = canvasEl.getContext("2d");

  canvasEl.width = Game.DIM_X;
  canvasEl.height = Game.DIM_Y;


  let startUpBackground = new Image();
  startUpBackground.onload = () => {

    ctx.drawImage(startUpBackground, 0, 0, Game.DIM_X, Game.DIM_Y);
    ctx.font = '48px serif';
    ctx.fillStyle = '#FFFFFF';
    ctx.fillText('Press Any Key', Game.DIM_X / 2, Game.DIM_Y / 2);
  };
  startUpBackground.src = "images/space.jpg";

  let startScreenListener = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('hi');
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, Game.DIM_X, Game.DIM_Y);
    const game = new Game();
    new GameView(game, ctx).start();
  };

  window.addEventListener('keydown', startScreenListener);

  window.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.removeEventListener('keydown', startScreenListener);
  });

});
```

Comment: I guess you are pressing cmd-r which reloads the page, and then releasing cmd-r once the script has loaded which triggers the "keyup" handler and its job is to remove the "keydown" handler, which it happily does.  You could set the keyup handler within the keydown handler to get around that.

Comment: That is what I expected was happening. I tried your suggestion and it worked! But I do not entirely understand why it worked. Is it because when I refresh the page the key down handler is not fired but as the page loads and I release the key the keyup handler fires removing my keydown handler? So by making the keyup handler a callback of keydown it delays the execution of the of keyup until keydown is executed?

Comment: There will be no keyup handler until keydown is triggered the first time.